# How can I create a UIActivity Indicator when logging in with the Parse framework?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I'm using the Parse framework for my app. I currently have it set up to where my users can login with a username and password but my question is how can i get a UIActivity Indicator to show when they are logging into the application with the Parse framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using `PFUser` for login, if so, Do like following code.

```
[[SMProgressHUD shared] showWithMessage:"LOGGING_IN" inTarget:APP_DELEGATE.navigationController.view];

        PFUser *loginuser = [PFUser user];
        [loginuser objectForKey:@"email"];
        [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:email password:password block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
            if(!error && user) {

                   [[SMProgressHUD shared] hide];

            } else {

                [[SMProgressHUD shared] hide];

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Invalid email address and password." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];

            }
        }];
```